# Latex large matrix

Tags: latex

I want to create this matrix.

```
$H=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & \ldots\ldots & 1 & 1 & 1 &\ldots & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & \ldots\ldots & 1 & 1 & 1 &\ldots & \alpha_{q-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & xxxxx & \vdots & xxxxxxx  & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & xxxxxx & \vdots\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 & \ldots\ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 &\ldots & \alpha_{q-1}\\
1 & 0 & 1 & \alpha_2 & \ldots & \alpha_{q-1} & \ldots\ldots & 0 & 1 & \alpha_2 &\ldots & \alpha_{q-1}
\end{bmatrix}$
```

I get this error

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 318--330


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 340--342

! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

l.344 ...& \ldots & 0 & \ldots\ldots & 1 & 1 & 1 &
                                                  \ldots & 1\\
?
```

Comment: Can you please make a [mre] that includes all the necessary packages etc. to compile your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the maximal number of columns in a matrix of `amsmath` is 10. But you can change that:

```
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{12}
```